# How do we handle errors in the input of a User Defined Literal?

Tags: c++, error-handling, c++17, operator-overloading

Say I want to have an integral percent defined like so:

```
constexpr int operator""_percent (char const * literal)
{
    int percent(0);
    for(; *literal != '\0'; ++literal)
    {
        if(*literal >= '0' && *literal <= '9')
        {
            percent *= 10;
            percent += *literal - '0';
            if(percent > 100)
            {
                ...what do we do here?...
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ...what do we do here?...
        }
    }
    return percent;
}
```

I was thinking of throwing, but I remember that a `constexpr` and `throw` do not match well (or is that only in C++14 and older?). What is the convention in that situation? What is the correct way to report an error in a User Defined Literal operator?

Note: I'm currently on C++17 but plans to soon switch to C++20.

Comment: Why do you limit percent values? 250%, -50% are well defined as 10%.

Comment: @273K For the sake of the example.

Comment: `std::strtol` is not a constexpr function, thus your entire literal operator is unable to be constexpr.

Comment: Is this about C++20 or earlier? In C++20 I would suggest making it `consteval` instead of `constexpr` and then throwing an exception is guaranteed to cause a compile-time error.

Comment: @user17732522 At the moment, I'm still on C++17, but that sounds great.

Comment: @AlexisWilke You might want to tag it C++17 then.

Comment: @user17732522 I'm hoping to switch to C++20 soon, so such a solution is also of interest.

Comment: Interestingly even the new standard library literal operators introduced with C++20 do not use `consteval` or any error reporting at all when the value is out-of-range, see e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22d. So I am wondering a bit whether there is something wrong with my suggested approach.

Comment: @user17732522: That’s just the preference of Howard Hinnant, who designed `<chrono>`.

Comment: @DavisHerring I can see why making it `noexcept` might have advantages if it is not `consteval`, but I am not seeing any advantage in not making it `consteval` with error reporting, except maybe to allow calling the operator directly with a runtime value, which doesn't seem like intended use to me. But as I said, I might be overlooking something.

Comment: @user17732522: You can use `throw` to fail constant evaluation even in a `noexcept` function.  I think the error-handling strategy is just for consistency with the runtime facilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really know what common practice for such situations is, but I will give some ideas below.

---

With C++20 you can make the literal operator `consteval` instead of `constexpr`.

On error you can then throw an exception. The `throw` expression itself is allowed in a `constexpr`/`consteval` function, but actually throwing makes it not a constant subexpression. Since `consteval` function invocations must be constant expressions, the program will then be ill-formed on error and the compiler must diagnose it.

---

For C++17 you can still throw an exception, but `consteval` is not available.

For valid literals this is not a problem. As long as the `throw` expression wouldn't be evaluated, the call to the literal operator can still be a constant subexpression.

If however the literal is invalid, you will generally not get a compile-time diagnostic if it isn't used in a context requiring a constant expression.

Instead you will get an exception thrown during program execution when the literal is evaluated. This might be undesirable, for example if the literal is supposed to be used in a `noexcept` function.

Alternatively you could also use `assert` instead of throwing exceptions. Since C++17 it is guaranteed to be a constant subexpression if the argument evaluates to `true`.

If the assertion fails, you will not get a compile-time error either, instead the program will abort when the literal is evaluated.

Using the `NDEBUG` macro the assertion can be removed in release builds. This doesn't affect the exception specification, but you will still need to decide on how to handle errors in the release build which weren't caught in debug build testing. This might not be safe enough for your use.

I don't think there is any C++17 way of forcing a compile-time error in general.

---

As I mentioned in the comments to the question, I have some doubts that my suggestions are correct/good. So read them as well, please.

Comment: Looking at the [chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22d) day operator, this is rather scary... saying that if you pass an invalid number, you get no diagnostic at all and it may even use some "random" number (probably `d & 255`) means you just can't be sure that things will do what you expect which I think is rather bad.

Comment: It's really not that scary.  `5000d` gives the exact same behavior as `day{5000}`.  Both compile and give you an unspecified result.  There are plenty of tools to observe and test the result.